# Javascript regex negative look-behind

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to figure out the correct regex to do this in javascript. In pcre, this does exactly what I want:

```
/^.*(?<!\/)kb([0-9]+).*$/im
```

Goal:

- If I have a value that isn't prefixed with a forward-slash, e.g KB**12345**, it'll match the number within.
- If that value is prefixed with a forward-slash it won't match, e.g:
  http://someurl.com/info/KB12345

However it looks like while this works in pcre, it won't work in javascript due to the syntax of the negation:

```
(?<!\/)
```

I've been trying to figure this out in regex101 but no luck yet. Any ideas or suggestions on what the pure-regex equivalent in javascript is?

I saw there's a negative look-ahead, but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
/^.*(?!\/KB)kb([0-9]+).*$/im
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex to match the right text:

```
/(?:^|[^\/])kb([0-9]+)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VHUOfD/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:^|[^\/])` - start of string or a char other than `/`
- `kb` - a literal string `kb`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more digits.

```js
var ss = ["If I have a value that isn't prefixed with a forward-slash, e.g KB12345, it'll match the number within.","If that value is prefixed with a forward-slash it won't match, e.g: http://someurl.com/info/KB12345"];
var rx = /(?:^|[^\/])kb([0-9]+)/i;
for (var s of ss) {
 var m = s.match(rx);
 if (m) { console.log(m[1], "found in '"+s+"'") };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciate the explanation as a learning point too!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
a = /^(?!\/KB)kb([0-9]+)$/i.test('KB12345')
b = /^(?!\/KB)kb([0-9]+)$/i.test('http://someurl.com/info/KB12345')
c = /^(?!\/KB)kb([0-9]+)$/i.test('/KB12345')

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```