# Negative lookbehind in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex:

```
https://(dev-|stag-|)(assets|images).server.io/v[\d]/file/(.*?)/(?!(download$))
```

- **Url 1:** https://assets.server.io/v3/file/blt123e25b85f95497/download.jpg
- **Url 2:** https://images.server.io/v3/file/blt123e25b85f95497/download
- **Url 3:** https://images.server.io/v3/file/blt123e25b85f95497/random.jpg

The intention is to **match Url 1 & 3 completely, but not Url 2**, but it doesn't seem to work.

By checking the following answers:
[Javascript regex negative look-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346875/javascript-regex-negative-look-behind), 
[Regex: match everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but), 
 I believe a negative lookbehind would work, but am unable to figure out what the regex for that would be.

Any help with it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Bw8bbD/1

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew, this seem to work! Thanks a million!

Comment: I posted the answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?!(download$))` part [by itself](https://regex101.com/r/b04gdT/1) isn't doing the right thing here since it fails the match if there is `download` and end of string immediately to the right of the last `/` matched. You need to actually match the last subpart with a consuming pattern to actually match the filename.

You may use

```
/https:\/\/(dev-|stag-)?(assets|images)\.server\.io\/v\d\/file\/(.*?)\/(?!download$)[^\/]+$/
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bw8bbD/3). If you need to match the whole string, add `^` anchor at the start of the pattern. `s` may be also made optional with `?` after it.

**Details**

- `https:\/\/` - a `https://` substring
- `(dev-|stag-)?` - an optional `dev-` or `stag-` substring
- `(assets|images)` - either `assets` or `images` substring
- `\.server\.io\/v` - a `.server.io/v` substring
- `\d` - any digit
- `\/file\/` - a `/file/` substring
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\/` - a `/`
- `(?!download$)` - there must not be a `download` substring followed with the end of string position immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `[\d]` is less readable than `\d`, and you need to escape `.` symbols in the pattern if you want to match literal dot chars.